# Azure Data Factory creates .CSV that's incompatible with Power Query

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a pipeline that creates a dataset from a stored procedure on Azure SQL Server.

I want to then manipulate it in a power query step within the factory, but it fails to load in the power query editor with this error.

[image]

It opens up the JSON file (to correct it, I assume) but I can't see anything wrong with it.

If I download the extract from blob and upload it again as a .csv then it works fine.

The only difference I can find is that if I upload a blob direct to storage then the file information for the blob looks like this:

[image]

If I just let ADF create the .csv in blob storage the file info looks like this:

[image]

So my assumption is that somewhere in the process in ADF that creates the .csv file it's getting something wrong, and the Power Query module can't recognise it as a valid file.

All the other parts of the pipeline (Data Flows, other datasets) recognise it fine, and the 'preview data' brings it up correctly. It's just PQ that won't read it.

Any thooughts? TIA

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced the same. When data is copied from SQL database to BLOB as csv file, Power query is unable to read. Also, Power query doesn't support json file. But when I tried to download the csv file and reupload, it worked.
Below are the steps to overcome this issue.

- When I tried to upload the file in Blob and create the dataset for that file in power query, Schema is imported from connection/Store.  It forces us to import schema either from connection/store or from sample file. There is no option as **none** here.[image: schema imported in power dataset]
- When data is copied from sql db to Azure blob, and dataset which uses the blob storage didn't have schema imported by default.
  [image: schema not imported]
- Once imported the schema, power query activity ran successfully.

**Output before importing schema in dataset**

[image: image before imporing dataset]

**After importing schema in dataset**
[image: image after imporing schema]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I don't import the schema I get an error when I try to add the dataset to the power query module - it tells me it needs the schema. I'd already encountered this. Now the .csv dataset does have the schema, but when I go to add it to a power query module the module crashes with the error as in my original message - it doesn't get as far as being able to add it to a pipeline since I can't even create the PQ element.

Comment: Not really an answer, if someone anyone desperately needs their dataset as .csv but I did manage a workaround with creating the dataset as parquet instead.

Comment: There is also this option to use the web activity and update the blob properties. Not used it myself since parquet works fine for me, but if anyone comes across this because they had the same issue and needs to work in .csv then hopefully it will be some help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/set-blob-properties

Comment: @Catríona What is the location of  your ADF?